# Symfony2: wkhtmltopdf footer url on server

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I used wkhtmltopdf with KnpSnappyBundle.
everything works nice on my dev machine, on Windows. I usually use `$snappyPdf->setOption('footer-html', $footer_url);` where `$footer_url` is the web url of the footer i want to use

But in production , it doesn't work at all: it display the url string instead of getting the html content.

There is my options used:

```
    $snappyPdf = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf');
    $snappyPdf->setOption('footer-html', $footer); // here is the problem?
    $snappyPdf->setOption('margin-left', 0);
    $snappyPdf->setOption('margin-bottom', '10mm');
    $snappyPdf->setOption('margin-top', '10mm');
    $snappyPdf->setOption('margin-right', 0);

    $snappyPdf->setOption('page-size', 'A4');
    $snappyPdf->setOption('zoom', 1 );
    $snappyPdf->setOption('dpi', 300 );
```

I tried:

```
  $footer = "www.google.fr";
  $footer = "http://www.google.fr";
  $footer = "'www.google.fr'"; 
  $footer = "'http://www.google.fr'";
  $footer = "myDomainNameUrl/myUrl";
```

none of them display the html in the footer, it display the string of the url I write...

Then I tried `$footer = "www.<b>google</b>.fr";` display www.**google**.fr with google in bold!!!
So I thought I could pass all the html via this parameter, and it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea? i'm feeling desperate!

My server is a `debian 7`, the wkhtmltopdf version is `0.12.2`

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm trying to resolve it following the suggestions reported on https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/104

Comment: I resolved it, I will post it soon, I have the code back home

Comment: @goto, Hi what is the solution please ??

Comment: @hous i post what i have in my old project code

Answer (score 0):

In order to print out the footer you need to use a wkhtmltopdf package with patched qt. You can check if wkhtmltopdf is able to add header or footer launching it from command line with the correct parameters (Symfony does not report the wkhtmltopdf warnings).

You can find the instructions to build a static version of wkhtmltox at https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/0.12.2.1/INSTALL.md#linux.

Check out your server version information with `wkhtmltopdf -V` and verify you actually see *(with patched qt)* after the version number.

Answer (score 0):

After 5 years:
The footer url has to be a insecure url : it should be accessible **without** login.
i used it as

```
 $snappyPdf->setOption('footer-html', $footer);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. in my case it was because the absence of `<!DOCTYPE HTML >`  https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/281